# I'm getting the correct uri but unable to load image into recyclerview?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, uri

I'm getting `ArrayList` of `Uri` in my `Fragment` Class and that's also been sent to the `adapter` class properly but image is not shown on the `recyclerView` after checking log cat I'm getting following error.I'm using Featured RecyclerView (a github libraray).

Error:

```
E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
```

Code of **`onCreateViewHolder()`**:

```
recyclerView =  v.findViewById(R.id.featured_recycler_view_society);
    FeatureLinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new FeatureLinearLayoutManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

           recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
  adapter = new CustomRecyclerViewAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext  (),selected);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

**`OnActivityResult`** code:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
if (requestCode == Constants.REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
    //The array list has the image paths of the selected images
    ArrayList<Image> images = data.getParcelableArrayListExtra(Constants.INTENT_EXTRA_IMAGES);
    ArrayList<Uri> selected=new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0, l = images.size(); i < l; i++) {
        selected.add(Uri.parse(images.get(i).path));
    }
  adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),selected.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                      }
}
```

Adapter Code:

```
public class CustomRecyclerViewAdapter extends FeatureRecyclerViewAdapter<CustomRecyclerViewAdapter.CustomRecyclerViewHolder> {

private Context context;
private ArrayList<Uri> image;

public CustomRecyclerViewAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<Uri> image) {
    this.context = context;
    this.image=image;

}

@Override
public CustomRecyclerViewHolder onCreateFeaturedViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    return new CustomRecyclerViewHolder(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.timeline_holder, parent, false));
}

@Override
public void onBindFeaturedViewHolder(final CustomRecyclerViewHolder holder, final int position) {
           try {


            link="file://"+image.get(position).toString();
            Toast.makeText(context,link, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
       Glide.with(context)
                .load(link).into(holder.ivBackground);
              } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }




}

@Override
public int getFeaturedItemsCount() {
    if(image==null){
        return 0;
    }
    return image.size();
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public void onSmallItemResize(CustomRecyclerViewHolder holder, int position, float offset) {

}

@Override
public void onBigItemResize(CustomRecyclerViewHolder holder, int position, float offset) {
       }

public static class CustomRecyclerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    ImageView ivBackground;

    public CustomRecyclerViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        ivBackground = itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_background);
                }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You should attach the `adapter` in your main `thread` and not in some `callback` like **`onActivityResult(..)`**. You can just update the `adapter` from callbacks by calling **`adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`**.

**UPDATED**

**onCreateView()**

```
recyclerView =  v.findViewById(R.id.featured_recycler_view_society);
FeatureLinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new FeatureLinearLayoutManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

       recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
selected=new ArrayList();
adapter = new CustomRecyclerViewAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext  (),selected);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

**onActivityResult()**

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == Constants.REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
        //The array list has the image paths of the selected images
        ArrayList<Image> images = data.getParcelableArrayListExtra(Constants.INTENT_EXTRA_IMAGES);
        for (int i = 0, l = images.size(); i < l; i++) {
            selected.add(Uri.parse(images.get(i).path));
        }
      adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),selected.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                          }
    }
```

Comment: Sir even after following your advise data is not loaded into recycler view

Comment: Sir I've added the adapter class please check the code ...@Deep Lathia

Comment: You're creating a new instance of the list selected in onActivityResult() that shouldn't be the case. You should initialise list in your create view before passing the list to adapter. I've updated my answer check it out

Comment: Unfortunately nothing changed by adding this